# python adding words to a list ignoring repeated words

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to ignore the repeated words in a text file .txt, and I've tried many things but none of them worked.

```
def words_in_file(filename):
       f = open(filename)
       word = []
       for line in f:
           word.append(line)
       return word
```

Comment: You can use a set to remember already seen words or you can check if the new word is already in "word" (less efficient).

Comment: I'm new to python, looking for a solution I can understand.

Comment: What didn't work? Please specify it.

Comment: I tried a counter and a lot of while, for and if cycles. But they didn't work because I am not that good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set`, which ignores duplicates.

```
def words_in_file(filename):
    words = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            words.append(line)
    return set(words)
```

*Note that I used `with`, which will make sure to close the file after using it or if there is an error.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your file but from your code it has nothing to do with what you want. But you can find unique words like this: `list(set(another_list))`. Only if your line has just one word, then change your code like this:

```
def words_in_file(filename):
   f = open(filename)
   word = []
   for line in f:
       word.append(line)
       another_list=list(set(word))
   return another_list
```

edit: And at the end don't forget to close your file.